# Quick Series Test Question

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

So I was given the following prompt:

"Determine the convergence or divergence of the following series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{n+1}{2n+1})^n$"

We're covering series and the different tests used to determine convergence or divergence and this example is giving me a bit of trouble. I understand most of the tests but I'm a bit confused about what test might need to be specifically used in this case. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As you have $n$ as exponent, the $n$-th root test could apply.

Comment: Just use the comparison test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your series is less than $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^n = 2$$ so it converges.

Answer (score 1):

If n is very big, then $a_{n} \approx \frac{1}{2^{n}}$. Converges.

Comment: Do you mean $a_n \approx \frac{1}{2^n}$?

Comment: Yes. I'm not so friendly with Latex. Thanks

Comment: \approx ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

By the root test (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Root_test_explanation) the series converges because you have $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|\frac{n+1}{2n+1}|^n}=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2}<1$.